# Unable to move Unity launcher or Menu Bar in Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-16.04

I have just upgraded my Ubuntu to 16.04 LTS, I want my launcher to be displayed in Mac style i.e. in the bottom of the screen. I tried changing couple of settings but nothing worked for me. Is it possible to achieve it? How? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Install **Unity Tweak Tool** in Ubuntu - 16.04 by typing the commands given below (one-by-one) in the terminal :-

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install unity-tweak-tool
```

Then open the Unity Tweak Tool. And click on **Launcher** which is under **Unity** part. Then change **Position** under **Appearance** to *Bottom* instead of *Left*. This will change the launcher's position from left to bottom(just like Mac). Another advantage of **Unity Tweak Tool** is that you can use it for doing other customisations/tweaks in Ubuntu. **Unity Tweak Tool** is a great configuration tool for Unity Desktop Environment !